# Angular2 with Redux - DOM reconciling

Tags: angular, redux, immutability, ngrx

I'm starting a new project with [Angular2](https://angular.io/) and [Redux](https://github.com/ngrx/store).

As an immutable object, when the **state** is changed, we create a new object and the Angular redraws all DOM again.
If the action was dispatched by an input element, the **focus is lost**.
 I've forked a sample plunk to reproduce the behavior: http://plnkr.co/yb53ij

In the real app, I've used the ".debounceTime()" from the forms API, but this not seem nice to user experience. There is a way to avoid this or I'm missing something?

The reducer code:

```
export const todos = (state = [{text: 'Edit my input...'}], {type, payload}) => {
  switch(type){
    case ADD_TODO: ...
    case UPDATE_TODO: ...
    case COMPLETE_TODO: ...
    case DELETE_TODO: ...
    case 'REPEAT_TODO':
      // Creates new state:
      return state.map(todo => {
        return todo.id !== payload.todo.id ?
          todo :
          Object.assign({}, todo, {times: payload.times})
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, we need to use the [trackBy](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4402#issuecomment-179342181) function of `*ngFor` directive. So we can tell to Angular to not render the DOM again. 
This can be a performance trap for uninformed developers like me! =P

```
@Component({
  selector: 'todo-list',
  template: `
    <div>
      <todo-list-item 
        *ngFor="#todo of todos; trackBy:custom"
        ...
      ></todo-list-item>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [TodoListItem]
})
export class TodoList {
  ...

  custom(index,item){
    return index;
  }
}
```

Here is the working plunker demo: http://plnkr.co/1ffRPD6F1vHw0EmHh5er